# jQuery add class if it exists elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I've just wrote the code below to add a class to the outer div where it matches. Now I know there must be a more elegant way to achieve the below!

```
if ($(".cur").hasClass("one")) { $("#outer").addClass("one"); }
if ($(".cur").hasClass("two")) { $("#outer").addClass("two"); }
if ($(".cur").hasClass("three")) { $("#outer").addClass("three"); }
if ($(".cur").hasClass("four")) { $("#outer").addClass("four"); }
if ($(".cur").hasClass("five")) { $("#outer").addClass("five"); }
if ($(".cur").hasClass("six")) { $("#outer").addClass("six"); }
```

Any improvements will be gladly received :)

Comment: Are there any other classes that `.cur` can have (apart from `cur`)? The simplest improvement would be to put `one...six` into an array and iterate over it.

Comment: OP are you here? can the `.cur` element have other classes apart those six?

Comment: @Vega. Of course, Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10390705/601179) to understand what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys and sorry for the delay in responding. I got called away from the desk.

Yes cur can have more than one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var classNames = '';    
$('.cur').each(function(){
    if (classNames.indexOf(this.className + ' ') === -1)
        classNames += this.className + ' ';
});

var classes = classNames.split​(" ");​​​
var $outer = $('#outer');    
$.each(classes, function(index, value){
    if (value !== 'cur')  
        $outer.addClass(value);
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pKdq7/5/)

**Notes:**

- With this code you don't need to "burn" the classes of `.cur` in the code, it's done automatically.
- It will copy all the classes of `.cur` (except `cur` itself), so it's up to you to decide if it's good for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the matching class using regEx and then add the matching class to #outer. See below,

```
$(function () {
    var regClasses = /(one|two|three|four|five|six)/g;
    var $cur = $('.cur'),
        $outer = $('#outer');

    $cur.each(function () {        
        $outer.addClass(this.className.match(regClasses).join(' '));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pKdq7/7/)

Comment: And if there are 6 classes to the `.cur` ? You take only the first class.

Comment: @gdoron I take the first matching class in the regEx, which should be one of the six. Isn't it?

Comment: But `cur` can have more than one class. like `<tag class="cur one three six" > </tag>`

Comment: See [my comment to @gdoron's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390665/jquery-add-class-if-it-exists-elsewhere/10390705#comment13398765_10390705). It applies to yours as well. And the original code will add *any* existing class, not the first existing class (it's no `if...else if`, just a bunch of `if`s (that's what gdoron wants to say)).

Comment: @FelixKling Check my updated answer, which should copy all matching in `.cur`

Comment: You are still assuming that there is only one `.cur` element though. This might not be the case.

Comment: You still didn't get it. Look at my updated answer, And I used your fiddle. You can see what is missing.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated to iterate thru all `.cur` and add class accordingly. Thanks for reviewing though.

Comment: @gdoron I think I got it this time.. check the updated answer and the demo. Was missing the iterate.

Comment: +1, though I don't like it too much as it "burns" the classes in the code. but it might be enough to the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Vega - I've accepted gdoron but thank you for your input. I've upped this.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    $cur = $('.cur'),
    $outer = $("#outer");

$.each(classes, function(i, v) {
    if ($cur.hasClass(v)) $outer.addClass(v); 
})
```

or iteration can be implemented as pure js like:

```
for (var i in classes) {
    var v = classes[i];
    ....
}
```

or (better) use `for` instead:

```
var len = classes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var v = classes[i];
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: ... or use it with `hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: Another of writing this could be: `$('#outer').addClass($.grep(classes, function(cls) { return $cur.hasClass(cls'); }).join(' '))`.

Comment: It'd be great if you could elaborate on your advice. Why shouldn't someone use for... in?

Comment: @Matt: Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) just above the examples. Apart from that, it's way slower than a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster as it doesn't call `.hasClass` on every iteration:

```
// define which classes you want to match
match_classes = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
// grab all the classes on the inner element
elm_classes = $(".cur").attr("class").split(" ");
// cache the outer element for quick access
$outer = $("#outer");

// iterate over the list of classes you want to match
$.each(match_classes, function(i, val){
// if one of those classes exists on inner, add it to outer
  if(elm_classes.indexOf(val) > -1) $outer.addClass(val);
});
```

Comment: You assume there is only one `.cur` element, which might not be true. and you're adding the `cur` class as well. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10390705/601179)

Comment: @gdoron i'm looping over the classes trying to be matched, not all the classes on .cur, and yes this could be easily modified to support finding the classes on multiple elements. Your answer, and my answer solve different problems that were too ambiguous to tell apart from the op's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
$.each(classes, function(key, value){
    if($('.cur').hasClass(value)) $('.cur').closest('div').addClass(value); 
});
```

Should do the trick, it uses closest('div') to get the outer div.

Comment: Why do you thing `.cur` is a descendant of `#outer`?

Comment: Why do you query the DOM six times (*2)... and there is already that kind of answer(but better...)